# Strange consistent log notices. Where do they come from?

Tags: drupal, cron-job, logs, civicrm.settings.php

I haven't tried asking on stackexchange before (only the old forums), so please excuse me if I do it in the wrong fashion... I did google this, but couldn't find anything that helped me remove these. I may of course have done something stupid again..

I have some cron-triggered notification messages that keeps appearing on every cron run. They are:

> Notice: Constant CIVICRM_USE_MEMCACHE already defined in include_once() (line 314 of /wwwroot/sites/example.org/civicrm.settings.php).
>
> Notice: Constant CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_HOST already defined in include_once() (line 320 of /wwwroot/sites/example.org/civicrm.settings.php).
>
> Notice: Constant CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_PORT already defined in include_once() (line 325 of /wwwroot/sites/example.org/civicrm.settings.php).
>
> Notice: Constant CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_TIMEOUT already defined in include_once() (line 331 of /wwwroot/sites/example.org/civicrm.settings.php).
>
> Notice: Constant CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_PREFIX already defined in include_once() (line 341 of /wwwroot/sites/example.org/civicrm.settings.php).

I'm worried they are more serious than they appear, and they anyway do clog up my log files. What could be the reason for these appearing?
I recently did an upgrade to version 4.6.4 (drupal 7.38), but I'm not sure if this was what triggered this.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: There is a forum thread referring to this error here https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=25725.15 in case the circumstances they are facing have any correlation to yours. What version did you upgrade from? Were there any warnings/notices as part of the upgrade that suggested problems had occured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's coming from `include_once` I suspect you have two `civicrm.settings.php` files.

The correct location is `sites/<default or example.org>/civicrm.settings.php`

If there's a file in `sites/civicrm.settings.php`, rename or remove it and see if that ends the errors.

--

EDIT: OK, having reformatted your question I can see the file path isn't actually `sites//civicrm.settings.php` ... StackExchange was hiding your sites directory because of the angle brackets.

SO - either you have two files (eg `sites/default/civicrm.settings.php` AND `sites/example.org/civicrm.settings.php`) OR your site somehow include_once's it after it's already included (?).

Let's use grep to look for files which define that constant:

```
grep -riE '^define.*CIVICRM_MEMCACHE' /path/to/site/root
```

If that identifies multiple files with this constant defined, then you probably want to eliminate one of those files. If it only locates a single file, then you may need to dig further to identify why that file is being included twice ... especially when the *second* time, it's being included using `include_once` :)